# xenserver low disk io performance

Tags: linux, performance, xenserver

I have XenServer 6.2 (updates applied XS62E001, XS62E002, XS62E004, XS62E005, XS62E007, XS62E008, XS62E009, XS62E010, XS62E011, XS62E012, XS62E013, XS62E014, XS62ESP1, XS62ESP1002) running a year in the HP ProLiant 380p g8 hardware.

Today it was slow, so I looked for the problem and found this:

## iostat -xm

Linux 2.6.32.43-0.4.1.xs1.8.0.847.170785xen (XXXXXXXX)       10/02/2015

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.29    0.00    0.42    0.05    0.90   98.33

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s   r/s   w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda              36.90     1.14 82.64 128.20     2.34     2.46    46.68     0.73    3.45   2.66  56.10
sda1             36.56     1.13  0.72  0.61     0.09     0.01   141.57     0.01    5.68   1.81   0.24
sda2              0.03     0.00  0.01  0.00     0.00     0.00     9.02     0.00    0.44   0.40   0.00
sda3              0.18     0.00 81.89 127.59     2.26     2.46    46.08     0.72    3.44   2.67  55.97
sdb               7.00     0.00  2.29  0.18     0.09     0.00    73.50     0.01    3.56   1.84   0.46
dm-0              0.00     0.00  0.00  0.00     0.00     0.00    20.90     0.00    2.00   0.50   0.00
dm-1              0.00     0.00  0.00  0.00     0.00     0.00    20.90     0.00    2.50   1.00   0.00
dm-5              0.00     0.00  0.03  1.33     0.00     0.01    15.58     0.00    2.02   0.90   0.12
dm-6              0.00     0.00  0.17  0.00     0.00     0.00    53.24     0.00    6.30   4.18   0.07
dm-7              0.00     0.00  0.04  0.00     0.00     0.00    23.01     0.00    8.35   7.05   0.03
dm-8              0.00     0.00  0.15  0.00     0.00     0.00    35.67     0.00    4.23   3.18   0.05
tdd               0.00     0.85  0.39  1.38     0.01     0.01    20.50     0.01    3.46   1.42   0.25
```

what might be causing this excessive traffic?

Sorry my english! :(